# Simple Socks over SSH tunnel in Andorid Java

Tags: java, android, ssh

I need to setup a socks proxy (tunnel) over ssh in android with java (android studio). I searched a lot but I couldn't find any solutions. This is my code:

```java
int assigned_port;
int local_port=8588;
int remote_port=22;
String remote_host = "server";
String login = "root";
String password = "password";
try {
    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    // Create SSH session.  Port 22 is your SSH port which
    // is open in your firewall setup.
    Session session = jsch.getSession(login, remote_host, 22);
    session.setPassword(password);
    // Additional SSH options.  See your ssh_config manual for
    // more options.  Set options according to your requirements.
    java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
    config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
   // config.put("Compression", "yes");
    config.put("ConnectionAttempts","2");
    session.setConfig(config);
    // Connect
    session.connect();
    // Create the tunnel through port forwarding.
    // This is basically instructing jsch session to send
    // data received from local_port in the local machine to
    // remote_port of the remote_host
    // assigned_port is the port assigned by jsch for use,
    // it may not always be the same as
    // local_port.
    assigned_port = session.setPortForwardingL(local_port,
            remote_host, remote_port);
} catch (JSchException e) {
    System.out.println("JSch:" + e.getMessage());
    return;
}
if (assigned_port == 0) {
    System.out.println("Port forwarding failed!");
    return;
}
```

There is no error but it didn't work. I need a simple code of socks tunneling.